# Storing model to file in VW's span_server mode

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Vowpal Wabbit has `--span_server` mode that let it train the model in parallel. I wonder how should I specify `-f` parameter in this case?
For example - I split my data in two parts and run following:

`$ ./cluster/spanning_tree
$ vw --span_server localhost --total 2 --node 0 -d part1.data --holdout_off
$ vw --span_server localhost --total 2 --node 1 -d part2.data --holdout_off`

I expect that both vw instances periodically communicate to sync feature weights. Thus at the end there should be one synced model that might be stored on disk with `-f`. Am I right? If so, should I add `-f model.file` to each vw command line? Will the last node detect that it's the last running node and save the model to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only need one of the nodes to write to a model file since allreduce will create the same model file for each node.